Difficulty to prove that a set is semi algebraic
I consider for $i\in\{1,…,N\}$ the subset $X_i\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that are convex and compact and semi algebraic. We denote by $X=\Pi_{i}^{N}X_i$ the Cartesian product of the $X_i$ which is still convex, compact for the natural vector space and topology structure induced by this product and semi algebraic.
I introduce, for $i\in\{1,…,N\}$, the functions $u_i : X\to\mathbb{R}$ that are continuously differentiable and concave with respect to the $i$-th variable and are polynomials of at most degree $\delta_i$. Now consider the set
$$
N=\left\{x = (x_1,….,x_N)\in X : \forall i\in \{1,…,N\}, \forall y_i\in X_i, \langle\nabla_{x_i}u_i(x), y_i - x_i\rangle\leq 0\right\}
$$
I would like to prove that $N$ is a semi algebraic set. My idea was to write this in terms of polynomials
$$
P_i(x,y_i) = \langle\nabla_{x_i}u_i(x), y_i - x_i\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial u_i(x)}{\partial x_{i,k}}(y_{i,k} - x_{i,k})\leq 0
$$
In order to write
$$
N=\left\{x = (x_1,….,x_N)\in X : \forall i\in \{1,…,N\}, \forall y_i\in X_i,P_i(x,y_i)\leq 0\right\}
$$
From this, I first thought that I was not far from the equivalence with a first order formula but when I checked the definition of such formula, I realized that the quantifiers I have (namely $\forall i\in\{1,…,N\}$ and $\forall y_i\in X_i$) were not allowed.
I would like to have your advice on this and/or some hints, since I am new to this subject do not hesitate to criticized the way I justify my argument and correct me if I am wrong please.
Thank you a lot

You're correct that quantifiers over a finite index set and bounded quantifiers are not part of the syntax of first-order logic. But it's easy to translate them into first-order logic.
Your formula is
$$\bigwedge_{i=1}^N \forall y_i \left(\varphi_i(y_i)\to P_i(x,y_i)\leq 0\right)$$
where $\varphi_i$ is a formula defining the semi-algebraic set $X_i$.

Thank you a lot for your answer !
